# How to animate adding HTML through Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension where I inject something onto website page. Since I am 'injecting' HTML into website page, the page loads first, and then some elements move down and my HTML appears which looks very abrupt and gives bad user experience.

I am doing something like this:

```
document.getElementById('element-id').innerHTML += myinnerhtml;
```

When this executes, some elements move down and myinnerhtml is injected.

Is there any way to animate is process ? (elements slowly move down and myinnerhtml slowly appears)

Comment: Never modify innerHTML directly as you destroy the attached listeners on child elements. Instead use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://devdocs.io/dom/element/insertadjacenthtml) or DOM manipulation. As for animation, see examples of CSS transition on `max-height`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using innerAdjacentHTML instead on innerHTML. And the css transition on max-height is sweet, why didn't I think of that :P.